# How can I convert the language into Arabic infermedica?

Tags: node.js

I want to convert Symptom Checker infermedica to Arabic language, I added apiModel infermedica-ar, but does not work.

```
    export default class InfermedicaApi {
      constructor (appId, appKey, apiModel = 'infermedica-ar', apiUrl = 'https://api.infermedica.com/v2/') {
        this.appId = appId;
        this.appKey = appKey;
           this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
        this.apiModel = apiModel;
        this.interviewId = null;
      }
```

Comment: Unless that application is already available in the target language, you will need a lot more than 6 lines of code (which do not mention language) to get it done. Can you explain why you expect your code to work?

Comment: @tucuxi full code https://github.com/infermedica/js-symptom-checker-example

Comment: I got Arabic data from the postman, But here it does not work.